# What is the difference between Events with Delegate Handlers and those without?

Tags: c#, events

What is the difference between this:

```
this.btnOk.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnOK_Click);
```

and this?

```
this.btnOk.Click += this.btnOK_Click;
```

They both work.  The former is what Visual Studio defaults to when you use the snippets.  But it seems like it only ads extra verbiage, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No difference. Omitting the delegate instantiation is just syntax candy; the C# compiler will generate the delegate instantiation for you under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

In C# 3.0 and later this is no difference. Before C# 3.0 EventHandlers were required due to compiler limitations, but with the advent of C# 3.0, the second form is preferred unless you want to be very explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that C# since 3.0 has implicitly added the delegate handler.  However, it can help to be more explicit, especially when there are multiple possible delegate types.

Answer (score 1):

"+= Delegate_Name" is a syntax sugar. Compiler will create new wrapper for you.