# Is there an actual difference in the 2 different ways of attaching event handlers in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, delegates, events, handlers

In C# is there any real difference (other than syntax) under the hood between:

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myMemberMethod);
```

and

```
myButton.Click += myMemberMethod;
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877/c-sharp-event-handlers)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second method is a shortcut to the first one, it was introduced in C# 2.0

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119160/what-is-the-difference-between-events-with-delegate-handlers-and-those-without).

Answer (score 5):

They are exactly the same, its called syntax sugar.

There are a lot of things that arent needed, to get a better idea of them while programming you should try something like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It will color the unnecessary code in Grey. Not to mention a whole myriad of incredible tools and refactorings.