# Wiring EventHandlers

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

Is there a difference between

```
Object.Event += new System.EventHandler(EventHandler);
Object.Event -= new System.EventHandler(EventHandler);
```

AND

```
Object.Event += EventHandler;
Object.Event -= EventHandler;
```

? If so, what?

Aren't they both just pointers to methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877/c-sharp-event-handlers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are Exactly same.
But

```
Object.Event += EventHandler;
Object.Event -= EventHandler;
```

The above example compiles fine only in 3.0 or later version of C#, while if you are in 2.0 or before 
you can only use following construct.

```
Object.Event += new System.EventHandler(EventHandler);
Object.Event -= new System.EventHandler(EventHandler);
```

Look more about at [Type inferencing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). search for "Type Inference"

Comment: A female who knows what type inferencing is? Oh god, please... Marry me? :-P lol

Answer (score 2):

No, they are exactly the same. The second version is purely a shorthand where the compiler creates an instance of the event handler for you. Just like simplified property syntax, using etc ... all compiler magic!

See this related question:

[Difference between wiring events using "new EventHandler<T>" and not using new EventHandler<T>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468868/difference-between-wiring-events-using-new-eventhandlert-and-not-using-new-ev)